# How do I copy blocks in LEGO 51515 block IDE?

Tags: programming, robot-inventor

I have been trying to copy and paste blocks in the new IDE that I downloaded from the Microsoft store (v 10.3.1). I do not seem to be able to copy block code from one project to another. How can I copy or export code to other block projects?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid it isn't possible to do this in the MINDSTORMS app.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste seems to work in the new "SPIKE 3" app at https://spike.legoeducation.com.